# ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of .. (errno: -1)

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, mysql-5.0

I am using Oracle MySQL 5.0.88 in CentOS 5.7 (64-bit). When i am trying to create an index to the tables means it shows

> mysql> CREATE  INDEX `activity_type_id` ON `activity_log`
>   (`activity_type_id`); ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of
>   './sample_production/activity_log' to
>   './sample_production/#sql2-665c-7' (errno: -1)

it's some what difficult to search with the error number. Please help me out why this error happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [`this`](http://miknight.blogspot.se/2009_05_01_archive.html) the problem may be related to `innodb_force_recovery` setting.

Run this to check if it's set to zero or not:

```
 SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_force_recovery';
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have a foreign key relation on that index. Then InnoDB doesn't let you do so. First of all, remove the foreign key first which is gonna remove the index anyway.
More information about the error 1025 check out [here.](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/08/22/mysqls-error-1025-explained/1)

Comment: In my database there is only 1 table is there.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a very similar error. In the end I discovered that SELinux was blocking me from making any changes to my tables. After adjusting the SELinux rules all is OK again.